# How do you install Octave packages on Mac OS El Capitan?

Tags: macos, installation, octave, package, macports

I tried installing packages (package io from Octave Forge) on Octave on a Macbook Air. Specifically with the following command `pkg install -forge io`. But it doesn't seem to work, and the following error is printed out

```
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0: line 512:  1600 Segmentation 

fault: 11  /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/g++-mp-4.7 -c -fPIC -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include -pipe-Os -m64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread csvexplode.cc -o csvexplode.o
make: *** [csvexplode.oct] Error 139
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0 csvexplode.cc

pkg: error running `make' for the io package.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/configure_make.m near line 82, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/install.m at line 199, column 5
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 394, column 9
```

I have tried the following instructions:

1. `code-select --install` from the Terminal window to install the
   command line tools Install MacPorts for Mac. This is a standard
   installer that you can download from Macports.
2. `sudo port install gcc48` --> This is a Fortran compiler, which is
   necessary for installing octave-general
3. `sudo port install octave-general` [NOTE: THIS TOOK A VERY LONG TIME,
   and I had to disable Spotlight indexing...Hours on a Macbook Pro]
4. `sudo port install octave-control`
5. `sudo port install octave-signal`

However it just stopped and the following is printed at `sudo port install octave-general`:

```
Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
--->  Computing dependencies for octave-general
--->  Dependencies to be installed: octave qscintilla qt4-mac dbus libmng texinfo texlive-basic texlive-bin harfbuzz-icu icu libzzip poppler openjpeg15 poppler-data potrace texlive-common xorg-libXaw xorg-libXmu xorg-libXi xorg-inputproto xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXp xorg-printproto texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex transfig netpbm libnetpbm
--->  Activating dbus @1.10.8_0
Error: org.macports.activate for port dbus returned: Image error: /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to activate port dbus. Use 'port -f activate dbus' to force the activation.
Error: Failed to install dbus
Please see the log file for port dbus for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_dbus/dbus/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: octave qscintilla qt4-mac dbus libmng texinfo texlive-basic texlive-bin harfbuzz-icu icu libzzip poppler openjpeg15 poppler-data potrace texlive-common xorg-libXaw xorg-libXmu xorg-libXi xorg-inputproto xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXp xorg-printproto texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex transfig netpbm libnetpbm
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port octave-general failed
```

I was wondering how you can install Octave packages on MacOS?

Comment: I'm not a MacOSX user but a few hints: Octave 3.8.0 is outdated, you should try a 4.0.x build. See http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X for instructions for macports, homebrew and fink. There is also a dmg for beginners. I can't see in your question which MacOSX version you are using

Comment: Sorry, actually using El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

Don't make things too complex!

There are a lot of dependencies (100+) for octave however!

NOTE: I first installed XCode via a "Regular GUI Application Install".

You might try using MacPorts there is a fairly easy install page with https://www.macports.org/install.php and also https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_macOS.

You need to first install MacPorts! and then you can run...

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port install octave
```

then to test if it worked type

```
$ octave
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

First, your versions of everything are old, it worked for me with the latest: `MacOS 10.13 + Xcode 9.2 + clang-4.0 (4.0.1 from Anaconda) + Octave 4.0.3`.

- For Octave 4.0.3 I used their [MacOS bundle](http://wiki.octave.org/Installing_MacOS_X_Bundle), not MacPorts. It's super fast, it includes GUI, and there's none of the delay with gcc48 you mentioned.

  - `pkg install -forge io` works for me (gets the package directly from Octave-Forge)
  - as to the MacPorts method, I can't speak for it, I never needed to use that (I use brew instead, but not for octave), it looks more painful and more error-prone. I expect using Octave's own Octave-Forge for package installs should be cleaner than ports, looking at your output from `sudo port install octave-*`. `Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed` looks like the wrong version of xcode is installed. So if you really wish to keep debugging that, look at the many solutions on SO or Apple to xcode. (You might only have command-line tools for Xcode, not a full Xcode install)
  - I get my [compiler tools (clang/clang++) from Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/compiler-tools.html), not gcc/g++
  - But honestly please update to the latest versions of everything (as above) and try again using only the Octave MacOS bundle and Octave-Forge not MacPorts, it should work.
  - FYI in general I was told back around 2015 people switched from MacPorts to brew, brew is said to be less brittle and easier-to-use. Similarly, Anaconda compiler tools work better than gcc/g++.